# Selecting a record via column_property

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 models simplified for the sake of this example (Domain, Visit) and I want to select the last visit timestamp for a given domain via column property

```
Domain.last_visit = db.column_property(
  db.select(
    [ db.func.ifnull( Visit.timestamp, 0 ) ],
    Visit.domain_id == Domain.id
  ).order_by(Visit.timestamp.desc()).limit(1).correlate(Visit.__table__).label('domain_last_visit'),
  deferred = True
)
```

My problem is that the value always returns `NULL` instead of `0`. I'm pretty sure it's because I don't know how to select the record I want and I placed that limit over there.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IFNULL` will only fallback to the `0` in case you have rows in `Visit` which have `timestamp = NULL`. But it does not cover the case when a `Domain` has no corresponding `Visit` records yet.

One way to achive that would be to use `MAX` aggregate instead of `ORDER BY ... DESC` and appy `IFNULL` on the result:

```
Domain.last_visit = column_property(
    select( [ func.ifnull(func.max( Visit.timestamp ), 0) ],
        Visit.domain_id == Domain.id
    ).correlate_except(Visit).label('domain_last_visit'),
    #deferred = True
)
```

Please note usage of `correlate_except` instead of `correlate` found in your code, which does not properly filter the results.

*You might also consider [Hybrid Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).*

Comment: @romeo-mihalcea: Thanks for accepting the solution. Would you share what/why exactly made it work in your case? Thanks!